# how to make 2 different on click in the same image to do 2 different things

Tags: javascript, html, css

Open slider when click on image and before this I did filter to the images so I want when open before filter; the slider show all images and after filter will show only the image at the filtered only at the slider

```html
<div class="gallery row" id="gallery" style="margin:0;">
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/11.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="height:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/111.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="height:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/131.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="height:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/141.png" alt="Card image cap" style="height:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 2 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/151.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="height:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="mb-3 pics animation all 1 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/121.png" alt="Card image cap" style="height:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)">
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->
</div>`
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update the snippet with relevant CSS and JS and images from placeholder.com to make a [mcve] and then elaborate on expected behaviour

Comment: An alternate and easy to debug solution will be calling these functions inside another function which contains both the functions inside it. BTW your code seems right so might be something else that you need to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried writing two functions inside a function?

```
function main_function($arg){
      openModal();
      currentSlide($arg);

}
```

and in html,

```
<img class="img-fluid" ... onclick="main_function(6);">
```

Comment: I need when I click on image show all images I had at the slider and after filter showing at the slider only the images at filtered one how can this help me to do that